# Trying to get property of non-object after OAuth2 in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting an error on one of my `foreach` statements. This is happening since I made the OAuth login to my project. The problem is once I made a post, once the name of the person who posts the article I get that error and it was working great until I did the OAuth.

Searching the error it says:

```
ErrorException in 90b25bff626151e496cbeba41de0d0cc13613e1c.php line 90:

The line 90 have: `<li><?php echo e($post->user->name); ?> &middot;</li>`
```

Here's the foreach on my index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12"> <!-- News -->
          <div class="thumbnail" onclick="location.href='{{ url('news/'.$post->slug) }}';">
            <div class="imageWrapper">
              <img src="{{ asset('imags/' . $post->postimg) }}" alt="feature-collection-image">
              <!-- <div class="masking"><a href="{{ url('news/'.$post->slug) }}" class="btn viewBtn">Leer Artículo</a></div> -->
            </div>
            <ul class="list-inline post-author">
              <li>{{ $post->user->name }} &middot;</li>
              <li><span class="badge">{{ $post->comments()->count() }}</span> comentarios</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="caption post-info">
              <h4>{{ substr($post->title, 0, 150) }}{{ strlen($post->title) > 150 ? "..." : "" }}</h4>
              <p>
                {{ substr(strip_tags($post->body), 0, 200) }}{{ strlen(strip_tags($post->body)) > 200 ? ". Leer más" : "" }}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        @endforeach
```

Before the OAuth it was working good, posts were displayed perfectly with the article creators name and on my news/single too but now...

I don't know what could be happening.

PD: I put the OAuth configuration on my LoginController and Config/Services.php if I remove the `{{ $post->user->name }}` everything works good but it will not display the post creator name.

Comment: Do you have any posts where the user key does not match to a user? Your error is indicating that it cannot find the `user` part of your chain. And subsequently it cannot retrieve a name.

Comment: On Admin dashboard and posts/show "where i can see the posts lists" the name shows correctly but now on index and news/single i can't.. dont know why..

Comment: If it works on one page, and not on the other, then you **must** be doing something differently. Review how you are retrieving it in your controller and how you are displaying it. There must be a difference somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Well is working good now i think it was a bad migration.

I made a new table called social_providers

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('social_providers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->references('id')->on('users');

        $table->string('provider_id');
        $table->string('provider');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

What i did was rollback all the migrations and i change that to this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('social_providers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('provider_id');
        $table->string('provider');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Run again my server "php artisan serve" create new admin, new user and a new post.. Now is working but i'm not sure if that was the problem.